# API.ai Google Home Web Simulator error: "Bot isn't responding now. Try again soon." Error: Failed to parse SDKResponse from http_response

Tags: json, web, dialogflow-es, google-home, api-ai

I restored an agent (working agent), using `Restore from Zip` option in `API.ai`. I tested the agent in API.ai and it worked successfully.

But when I try to integrate it with Google Home, and test it with the Google Home Web Simulator, I get the error:

`"Bot isn't responding now. Try again soon."`

Here is the `Response Json`:

`"Failed to parse SDKResponse from http_response: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length: 230\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nDate: Tue, 09 May 2017 07:13:04 GMT\r\nServer: nginx/1.11.2\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\nAssistant-Interaction-Error-Code: 1\r\nAssistant-Interaction-Error-Message: Empty speech response\r\nCache-control: no-cache=\"set-cookie\"\r\nSet-Cookie: AWSELB=9D5B4D210CCFFAF1BE1E0CD7C7E6FCBD7B46140CAAB35B563903DCE43FCC26342E3F89041AE3FE415E45579D21DA955B71D82B5CBB83188E876559AECB9AFBA466D1A80189;PATH=/\r\nX-Cache: Miss from cloudfront\r\nVia: 1.1 3212ba6c9a2d0009095ca19f00206ff3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)\r\nX-Amz-Cf-Id: LUDwKPkUCwQJuK1elUUy3ZUZXTz-qcegNKGMUJv5Hb4k2a_ea2tRqg==\r\n\r\n{\"message\":\"Empty speech response\",\"apiResponse\":{\"id\":\"cd783d0c-11ab-438a-91ac-167f7998d678\",\"timestamp\":\"2017-05-09T07:13:04.382Z\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1494313984341\"}}'"`

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

Reading the `Response JSON`, I noticed: `Empty speech response`. I rechecked my API.ai code and noticed that one of the `Intents` (in my case the `Default Welcome Intent`) was giving output `Empty speech response.` While on the console of API.ai this is not an issue, when you try linking to Google Home Web Simulator, it doesn't work. So in case you have a similar issue, maybe the first step of troubleshooting is figuring out which `Intent` is giving `Empty speech response`.

Hope this helps anyone else who faced a similar problem.

Comment: It looks like the response you're sending back isn't valid. Can you show us the code that is sending the JSON response? There is also a mention of an "Empty speech response".

Comment: @Michael You are right - the issue was the "Empty speech response". I have solved the problem.

Comment: Please add the solution **as an answer** and mark it as accepted. Thanks! :)